# Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RCTAsyncStorage.multiMerge' (React-native-asyncstorage)

Tags: react-native, expo, asyncstorage

I am having an issue related to react-native-asyncstorage from here:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html

When I run `react-native run-ios`, the following error appears:
[image]

I am using react-native 0.52.0 and this problem may be due to the dependency of react-native-asyncstorage:

> react-native-asyncstorage@1.0.0 requires a peer of
>   react-native@^0.47.2 but none is installed. You must install peer
>   dependencies yourself.

The odd thing is it works fine for Android, but not for both iOS nor iOS emulator.

Can someone help?

**EDIT**

I would like to add some points that maybe useful:

- I use [Expo](https://expo.io/) for development,
- I have commented every AsyncStorage in my code, but the problem still persist,
- As asked in the comment, here is the snipped code of my AsyncStorage code

-

```
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
export async function SetItem(strKey, objValue) {
    try {
        if (typeof(objValue) === 'string') {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem(strKey, objValue);
        }
        else {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem(strKey, JSON.stringify(objValue));
        }
    } 
    catch(error){
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you`ll share your code that uses the AsyncStorage.

Comment: @KirillGlazunov edited in the post.

Comment: I have just started having this same issue.  Have you had any luck solving it?  When I deploy the app through TestFlight, it's fine.  It's just a build through Xcode that has this problem.

Comment: In the end, my team decided to remove Expo completely from the project. Then, it works. Nevertheless, I don't think this way as the best solution.

Answer (score -1):

Like said in the documentation: **NOTE: This is not supported by all native implementations**, you're probably running in an error because of this.

It may also be **Reactotron** you're using (according to the stack trace) that causes this. Try disabling it at first?

Are you having a custom implementation of `AsyncStorage` (like: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-asyncstorage)? If so, take it off unless there's a specific reason to use it (please elaborate in the question)

But in general, you could for instance use [React Native Simple Store](https://github.com/jasonmerino/react-native-simple-store/) and it's `update` method.

Or then you could write your own function with [lodash.merge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.merge).

If problem persists even with commenting out all the AsyncStorage code, removing possible custom dependencies and taking off Reactotron, and you can't find a way to write multiMerge by yourself, update your question and ping me on this answer.