# React-Native Simple Store Error: Unable to load RocksDB, SQLite, or AsyncLocalStorage

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios, asyncstorage

When running a basic app that uses `react-native-simple-store` I get the following error (the same as [this unsolved question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50075823/undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-rctasyncstorage-multimerge-react-nativ)):

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RCTAsyncStorage.multimerge')

<unkown>
AsyncStorage.js:325:21
...
```

Digging into AsyncStorage.js I find that the issue is here:

```
// Not all native implementations support merge.
if (!RCTAsyncStorage.multiMerge) {
  delete AsyncStorage.mergeItem;
  delete AsyncStorage.multiMerge;
}
```

`RCTAsyncStorage` is not undefined. The attempt to define `RCTAsyncStorage` comes at the beginning of the same file.

```
const NativeModules = require('../BatchedBridge/NativeModules');

// Use RocksDB if available, then SQLite, then file storage.
const RCTAsyncStorage = NativeModules.AsyncRocksDBStorage ||
  NativeModules.AsyncSQLiteDBStorage ||
  NativeModules.AsyncLocalStorage;
```

Finally, I checked `NativeModules.AsyncRocksDBStorage`, `NativeModules.AsyncSQLiteDBStorage`, and `NativeModules.AsyncLocalStorage`—surely enough, all of them were undefined. The file from which they are supposed to be loaded (NativeModules) is a bit difficult to understand, so I stopped tracing there.

Please let me know if you know what I could be doing wrong!

Comment: npm list react-native,I think there should be two different react-native package .

Comment: There seems to only be one: 
```npm list react-native
whattowear@0.1.0 /Users/rohanp/hack/what-to-wear
└── react-native@0.55.4```

Comment: Attach to your question your `package.json` file and the code where you try to access the store.