# RCTAsyncStorage.multiMerge undefined

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

[image]

All I did was pull a previously working branch and I received this error. Also, I have tried to remove all the usage I had of AsyncStorage but still the issue persisted.

Comment: I answered this question long time ago (got minus points, so apparently it was incorrect answer :D). But you could check whether if offers any guidance: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50081096/212878

Comment: You mentioned disabling Reactotron, how to I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue. I suspect the issue was caused by two things, a corrupt cache that failed to update whenever the app reloaded, secondly the memory on my machine was full, it has been two weeks since I shut down my machine, 
so what I did :

1. I run `rm -rf node_modules/`
2. Quit all running programs
3. Deleted a few files to make space on my Disk.
4. Restarted the machine.
5. After restarting, I open the project, and ran `npm install`
6. Then lastly I ran `react-native start --reset-cache`